# Dynamic allocation of a matrix using classes returns something like "21.684268-3121"

Tags: c++, oop, matrix

```
class Vector {
protected:
    unsigned int dim;
    float *a;
public:
    Vector() {
        a = NULL;
        dim = 0;
    }
    Vector(const unsigned int& x) {
        dim = x;
        a = new float[dim];
        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < x; index++) {
            cin >> a[index];
        }
    }
    Vector(const float *init, const unsigned int& size) {
        if (init) {
            dim = size;
            a = new float[size];
            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
                a[index] = init[index];
            }
        }
    }
    void initVector(const float *init, const unsigned int& size) {
        if (init) {
            dim = size;
            a = new float[size];
            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
                a[index] = init[index];
            }
        }
    }
    void initVector(const unsigned int& size) {
        dim = size;
        a = new float[dim];
        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            cin >> a[index];
        }
    }
    unsigned int getDim() {
        return dim;
    }
    float operator[](unsigned int pos) {
        return a[pos];
    }
    ~Vector() {
        delete[] a;
    }
    friend class Matrice;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Vector&);
};

class Matrice {
protected:
    Vector *v;
public:
    Matrice() {
        v = NULL;
    }
    Vector operator[](int pos) {
        return v[pos];
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Matrice&);
};

class Matrice_oarecare : public Matrice
{
protected:
    unsigned int linii;
public:
    Matrice_oarecare() {
        linii = 0;
    }
    Matrice_oarecare(int coloane, int linii) {
        this->linii = linii;
        v = new Vector[linii];
        for ( int index = 0; index < linii; index++) {
            cin >> v[index]; //Asta apeleaza >> pentru Vector, care citeste toate numerele din sir
        }
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrice_oarecare&a);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrice_oarecare&a);
};

class Matrice_patratica : public Matrice {
    unsigned int dim;
public:
    Matrice_patratica() {
        v = NULL;
        dim = 0;
    }
    Matrice_patratica(unsigned int dim) {
        this->dim = dim;
        v = new Vector[dim];
        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < dim; index++) {
            float *init = new float[dim];
            for (unsigned index2 = 0; index2 < dim; index2++)
                cin >> init[index];
            v[index].initVector(init, dim);
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Matrice_patratica&);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Vector& v) {
    in >> v.dim;
    v.a = new float[v.dim];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.dim; i++)
        in >> v.a[i];
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Matrice_oarecare& a) {
    for (unsigned indexI = 0; indexI < a.v->getDim(); indexI++) {
        for (unsigned indexJ = 0; indexJ < a.linii; indexJ++) {
            os << a[indexI][indexJ];
        }
    }
    return os;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Matrice_patratica& a) {
    for (unsigned indexI = 0; indexI < a.dim; indexI++) {
        for (unsigned indexJ = 0; indexJ < a.dim; indexJ++) {
            os << a[indexI][indexJ];
        }
    }
    return os;
}
int main() {
    Matrice_oarecare c(2,2);
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have some problems while trying to dynamic allocate a matrix. Whatever I write, it return something like '21.3244141e-48198' and idk why. I think that the problem might be either the overloaded << operator, or one inheritance.
The 'Matrice_oarecare' and 'Matrice_patratica' have to inherit the Matrice class, and I have to create them using the Vector class.

Comment: *it return something like* -- What is "it"?  Please post a [mcve] and explain exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I said 'something like' because it returns something different everytime. For example, when I tried to create a simple 2 x 3 matrix (1 2 3 4 5 6) it returned 22.58613e-037.

Comment: The word `return` means something in C++.  What function are you calling that returns this value you're speaking of?  You also haven't posted what was asked, a [mcve].  A class by itself does nothing without code that uses the class.

Comment: Show the code that uses this class and writes out things.

Comment: You're missing copy constructors in your classes.  Search on "rule of three" or "rule of five".

Comment: This is the whole code actually.

Comment: @user8113290 -- Are you running a program?  If so, how can this be the whole code?  Where is the `main` function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the main only had " Matrice_oarecare c(2,2);
 cout << c << endl;"

Comment: @user8113290 It doesn't matter what `main` only has, please put the `main` function in your post.

Comment: @user8113290 that should be included in your program. What are you *expecting* from that, btw? That should also be in your post.

Comment: Done, I edited it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't really see where/why I need a copy constructor.

Comment: [Maybe reading this will explain why.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You have a blatant rule of three/five/zero violation. Your `Matrice::operator[]` returns `Vector` by value, which makes a shallow copy of all members including pointers. When that object is destroyed those pointers are left dangling in the original `Matrice` hosted `Vector` object, which, when destroyed or accessed again (such as your iteration loop) will now puke all over itself. Running this in a decent debugger would have shown you all of this.

Comment: @user8113290 *I don't really see where/why I need a copy constructor.* -- Try this two line program : `int main() {Vector v(1); Vector v2 = v; }`  This results in a double deletion error on exit of `main`.  The `Vector` class requires proper copy semantics, and you didn't provide them, as the comment by WhozCraig points out.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: if your class has pointer members you need to implement copy/move constructors/assignment operators (possibly `=delete` if you don't want them) - since the compiler generated versions will probably *not* do what you want in 99.999% of all cases when you have pointer members.

Comment: A constructor which reads from stdin is strange, to say the least.

Comment: This: `Vector() {
        a = NULL;
        dim = 0;
    }` really wants to be: `Vector() : dim{0}, a{nullptr} {}`.